# Is there any API supported by Android for recording phone call?

Tags: android

Is there any API supported by Android for recording phone call ?

Thanks and Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Call recording is not yet possible on Android. See this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226).

You can record your voice from microphone, but you can not record the sound of the other party. If you only want to record your voice use android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC

Comment: Any update on this? I've seen that newer phones support the API elements that have been broken in 1x gen phones. I haven't seen a specific list.