# Android voice call recorder

Tags: android, inheritance

Hi all I am looking for any API or lines of codes that can guide me how I can record android incoming and outgoing call ?
I read some discussion from [Is there any API supported by Android for recording phone call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371496/is-there-any-api-supported-by-android-for-recording-phone-call) and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226 where they guide its not possible to record android calls due to device limitations etc.I also explore android auto answer app that's on http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/ but this app also do auto ans by following different option like ringing call duration etc.any one can guide in detail how i can record twoway voice ?how i can detect it call is answer,reject by caller and receiver person ?thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801368/can-anyone-give-code-for-voice-recorder-as-an-application-on-android-phone) is a old post that might help you..

Comment: @Anand Sainath thanks . . the link you share related to voice recording.I already done code for voice recording.but need to find calls state and both side recording . .

Comment: hi all using call state I able to record the incoming call and my recording start when i answer the call that is working fine now,but now problem is how I can detect outgoing call receiver receiver/reject my call ? I find the way to detect outgoing call with "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" but unable to find when receiver receive my call or reject (cancel) it .anyone can guide  ? thanks